# Find compression ratio of a compressed binary Image

Tags: python

It is known from the compressed_image.bin file that an 8-bit gray-scale image is encoded using the run-length method. The first two bytes contain the width Nx and height Ny, all other two bytes contain the code pairs (count, symbol). The image is an array and i need to calculate the compression rate of it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


file_handle = open( "compressed_image.bin" , "rb" )
compr_img = np.fromfile(file_handle, dtype='uint8')
```

i wrote this program to read the binary image, do i need to decode it and then find the compression ratio? i would appreciate some help :)

[Debugger view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkX1K.png)

Comment: It seems all you need are the image dimensions and the length of the `compr_img` array - you don't need to actually decode all the pixels.

Comment: can you tell me more how do i do that with only the len and dimensions?

Comment: You know that "compression ratio" means the result when you divide the uncompressed size by the compressed size, right? If you have the length of the `compr_img` array, do you understand how that relates to the compressed size? If you have the height and width of the image, do you understand how you can use that to know how many pixels are in the image? If you know how many pixels there are, and how much space is needed per pixel in the raw format, then you can tell the uncompressed size, right? What exactly is the difficulty?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears that OP really has a math (or logic?) question, not a programming question.

Comment: so i calculate the number of pixels in the image by multiplying the width with the Height but how do i know how much space is needed per pixel in the raw format if i only have the compressed image? Thank you !